# Different query result on local and server

Tags: wp-query, multisite, wp-mail

I create plugin to sent list post yesterday and today via wp_mail() to member from WordPress multisite, at localhost the result of list post delivery successful.

But at live server, the result of post displaying mix last month, last year post.
Code

```
function test_plugin() {
$blogs = get_last_updated(' ', 0, 40);
global $wpdb;
//find today post from WordPress network
foreach ($blogs AS $blog) {    
    switch_to_blog($blog["blog_id"]);
    $today = getdate();
    $yesterday = date('F jS, Y',strtotime("-1 days"));
    $yesterday_today = array(
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after'     => $yesterday, //'January 1st, 2013',
                'before'    => array(
                    'year'  => date('Y'),
                    'month' => date('n'),
                    'day'   => date('j'),
                ),
                'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query($yesterday_today); ?>
    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <!-- the loop -->
        <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); 
            $result = get_the_date('Y-m-d')." | ".get_bloginfo()." | ".'<a href="'.get_permalink().'?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=budayasaya'.'">'.get_the_title()."</a><br>";
            $content[]=$result;
            ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php restore_current_blog(); ?>
    <?php 
}
//save result as one variable
$list_post = implode(" ", $content);
//Check if any post, sent it
if ($list_post != NULL) {
    echo "This will sent email to users with content: <br>".$list_post;
    $subject = 'Daily News';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
//sent email to multiple recipients
    $get_email = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT email FROM penerima WHERE status = '1'");
    foreach ( $get_email as $recipients ) {
        $to = $recipients->email;
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $list_post, $headers ); 
    }
}
}
```

My git https://github.com/ahmadbagwi/testemailblast/blob/master/index.php

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using the same date format for `yesterday` and `today` (after and before)?
Also it looks like you're not using `$today` variable anywhere...

Comment: It just try and error, I use $today before and now use $yesterday, $yesterday_today. The result same give me mix result on email body when sending with live server

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using another date format? Example:

```
foreach ($blogs AS $blog) {    
    switch_to_blog($blog["blog_id"]);
    $yesterday_today = array(
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after'    => array(
                    'year'  => date('Y',strtotime("-1 days")),
                    'month' => date('n',strtotime("-1 days")),
                    'day'   => date('j',strtotime("-1 days")),
                ),
                'before'    => array(
                    'year'  => date('Y'),
                    'month' => date('n'),
                    'day'   => date('j'),
                ),
                'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    //....
```